# C# decompiler restoring async/await methods

Tags: c#, decompiler

I tried a number of C# decompilers (dotPeek, Reflector, ILSpy, the one from Teleric) but none of them restores async methods as they look before compilation. Is there any decompiler  restoring async/await?
My base problem is to migrate nuget package from Xamarin iOS project to x64 Unified iOS project.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want something like [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) which decompiles to `async` and `await` keywords as shown in this screenshot I took from version 5:

[image: dnSpy screenshot]

Version 4 was not able to decompile async/await.